# Python urllib2: read data as soon as it comes

Tags: python, http

I have a specific HTTP server that accepts incoming connection and keeps it opened, send data from time to time, like chat messages.

I tried to use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2

url = "http://localhost/chat"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in urllib2.urlopen(url):
        print line
```

That should print chat messages as soon as they arrive until user terminate the script. In fact this script waits 1 minute, than prints every message arrived during this minute, and exit.

Is there a way to force python to keep connection opened and print received data immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `urllib2` maintains its buffer, and you can’t do what you want using `urllib2` (in documented way, at least).  You’d better directly use `httplib`.